# macOS El Capitan iTunes does not list songs when you click on the album

Tags: itunes, macos

Since recently my iTunes Version 12.8.2.3 running on El Capitan does not show songs when you click on the album in Browser. It leads to an empty panel.

Might this be something that’s a bug or reproducible?

Comment: Which version of iTunes?

Comment: Version 12.8.2.3